# Get to system settings in google now launcher

Tags: settings, google-now

How do I get to the normal system settings?  I seem only be able to find search settings.

Comment: Notification bar pull-down twice (lollipop) or quick settings (kitkat)

Comment: What phone do you have, and version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's a settings app in the application drawer.